# loading arm shared objects on an armhf system using dlopen

Tags: linux, arm, shared-objects

Is there a way to load shared objects compiled for arm(el) on an armhf system (Ubuntu 12.10 for armhf)?
For executables I solved the Problem by creating the following symbolic link

/lib/ld-linux.so.3 -> /lib/ld-linuxarmhf.so.3

A look at strace output (last lines of trying to load data_nohf/test.so) seems that even no mapping of the binary is done by dlopen.

```
open("data_nohf/test.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0(\356\2\0204\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 1456412, SEEK_SET)             = 1456412
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1080) = 1080
lseek(3, 1456140, SEEK_SET)             = 1456140
read(3, "A(\0\0\0aeabi\0\1\36\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\22\4\24\1\25\1\27"..., 41) = 41
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

Comment: Why there is a different loader for hf?

Comment: @auselen For reasons/decision for different loaders take look at [link](https://wiki.linaro.org/OfficeofCTO/HardFloat/LinkerPathCallApr2012)

Comment: there is no answer there. Someone should be able to say like "it looks for different method signatures" or "it is just a name change"

Answer (score -1):

The reason not to support armel (binaries) on armhf systems is mentioned in 
[Debian Hard Float (armhf) for RPi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=4256&start=575)

Comment: For further details take a look at [Debian ARMHF](http://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort#ARM_EABI)